# Powershell input CSV in UTF7 - Output in UTF 8 problem with some character

Tags: powershell, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a client who requires a database export from a SQL Server 2016 database in UTF8 no BOM. I've used PowerShell to import the raw output from the database (which is in ANSI) and output the file in UTF-8.

Now I am hearing back if I could remove some 'special characters', and saw that PowerShell has changed it as shown in the picture.

Is there any way PowerShell could keep the character or remove it entirely?

This might also happen with other characters in the future, our sample dataset only contains this particular character.

[image]

EDIT: The Customer has a batch script which exports a select request from a MSSQL Server to a CSV File. Script as follows:

```
sqlcmd -S [SERVER]\[INSTANCE] -U sa -P [PASSWORD] -d [DATABASE] -I -i "C:\Path\To\Query.sql" -o "C:\Path\For\Output\Ouput.csv" -W -s"|"
```

The CSV is seperated by a Pipe.
The request was then to add double-quotes as text identifier as well as change the encoding to UTF-8 no BOM. The Database apparently exports the file in ANSI.

I've created a powershell script since I know it will automatically add the double quotes for me and I should be able to change encoding through it.

Script goes as follows:

```
$file = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Path\For\Output\Ouput.csv" -Encoding "UTF7" -Delimiter "|"

$file | Export-Csv  -path "C:\Path\For\Output\Ouput.csv" -delimiter "|" -Encoding "UTF8noBOM" -NoTypeInformation
```

The reason for the -Encoding UTF7 flag in the input step was that without it, we had problems with special letters like `ß` and `äöü` (we're in Germany, those will be frequent).
After running the file through this script, it's mostly as it should be however the example in the screenshot is a problem for the people trying to import the file into their system afterwards.

Did this help? I'll gladly provide any further information, thank you in you advanced!

EDIT: Found a solution. I've edited the customers original script which creates the export from the database, I've added the -u flag making the output Unicode. It's not UTF8 yet but the powershell script can now convert the file properly, also no need to set import encoding to UTF7. Thanks to JosefZ for questioning my use of forced UTF7 encoding, made me realise I was looking at the wrong place to fix this.

Comment: so ... what was the original data that you loaded into PoSh ... and how did you load it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (note that images are unwelcome).

Comment: It had to look up [UTF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) in Wikipedia. PowerShell tends to produce UTF-16 when you use redirections, but I can't figure out how you're using it here or why you even need it. Can you please edit the question and explain things in more detail? You really want to prevent text corruption, not revert it after it happens.

Comment: Edited, let me know if that clarified things a little.

Comment: Why do you force `-Encoding UTF7`? It contradicts your assertion that _… raw output from the database (which is in ANSI)_!

Comment: Because if I don't, the data in Powershell messes up äöü ß characters.